# How can I transfer all carrier settings from an existing phone to a new phone?

Tags: sim-card, data-transfer, apn

I have been provided a device for a telephone carrier that cannot be joined automatically. When the Sim is inserted into another phone, it cannot find/connect to the network. Due to the nature of the network I am on, and given I was supplied the phone from the telephone carrier, I believe its customized in some way.

I want to use this network and sim card, but on a better phone (Razer Phone 2).

Is there some mechanism I can use to transfer all settings from one phone to the other, including whatever secret settings the carrier may have setup prior to handing out the devices?

Comment: Dial `*#*#*4636#*#*` and in the phone menu see under carrier related information.

Comment: `*#*#4636#*#*` does nothing on this phone. When entered, it simply disappears and the menu that should appear, doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to settings, find your settings for you sim (APN) settings and from there be able to copy these settings to your new phone.

I am assuming your current device is an android device. On my phone (OPO5T) I can simply go to settings->Wi-Fi & internet->SIM & network->(My sim card)->Access Point Names.

Comment: This does not result in successful connection to the carrier. There appears to be some other setup / information that is beyond that controlled in the APN settings that permits connection.

Comment: @Predominant what carrier are you using? also make sure the APN settings are correct, you can always double check, you could also check the carriers website for APN settings.

Comment: I cannot say the carrier I am using. The provided phone has some configuration beyond simple APN settings, and that is the information I wish to discover, or simply transfer to another phone.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge to do all these things I would simply go to Connections ->Mobile Network->Access Point Names->Select your carrier-> click on the 3 vertical dots and a dialogue box is opened->Click Save ->email the settings->open your new mobile and access your email->copy all the settings and paste it on your Razor Phone 2 APN(Access Point Name)

I hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Razer phone 2 will not work on Verizon CDMA/LTE

Many Prepaid Carriers will not let you use unlocked phones.

You have to verify it on their site: Looking for a "Bring your own phone" option.

Pending that checks out

1. Insert Card
2. Settings - Connections -> find "Mobile settings --> APN/Access point names"
3. Top right [New]
4. You have to fill in these blanks: You will have to google "LTE APN settings ATT/Tmo/etc.."

Comment: I'm not using Verizon.